# Find cosine similarity between two arrays

Tags: arrays, r, distance, similarity, trigonometry

I'm wondering if there is a built in function in R that can find the cosine similarity (or cosine distance) between two arrays?

Currently, I implemented my own function, but I can't help but think that R should already come with one.

Comment: Does R really need a new function just for `x %*% y / sqrt(x%*%x * y%*%y)`?

Comment: This post shows how to create a cooccurrence matrix and then calculate the cosine similarity - http://stackoverflow.com/a/24627329/168689

Comment: Also check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158867/most-efficient-r-cosine-calculation

Answer (score 70, accepted):

These sort of questions come up all the time (for me--and as evidenced by the *r*-tagged SO question list--others as well):

*is there a function, either in R core or in any R Package, that does x?* and if so,

*where can i find it among the +2000 R Packages in CRAN?*

short answer: give the ***sos package*** a try when these sort of questions come up

One of the earlier answers gave *cosine* along with a link to its help page. This is probably exactly what the OP wants. When you look at the linked-to page you see that this function is in the *lsa* package.

But ***how would you find this function if you didn't already know which Package to look for it in?***

you can always try the standard R help functions (">" below just means the R command line):

```
> ?<some_name>

> ??<some_name>

> *apropos*<some_name>
```

if these fail, then install & load the ***sos*** package, then

```
***findFn***
```

*findFn* is also aliased to "???", though i don't often use that because i don't think you can pass in arguments other than the function name

for the question here, try this:

```
> library(sos)

> findFn("cosine", maxPages=2, sortby="MaxScore")
```

The additional arguments passed in ("maxPages=2" and "sortby="MaxScore") just limits the number of results returned, and specifies how the results are ranked, respectively--ie, "find a function named 'cosine' or that has the term 'cosine' in the function description, only return two pages of results, and order them by descending relevance score"

The ***findFn*** call above returns a data frame with nine columns and the results as rows--rendered as HTML.

Scanning the last column, *Description and Link*, item (row) 21 you find:

**Cosine Measures (Matrices)**

this text is also a link; clicking on it takes you to the help page for that function in the Package which contains that function--in other words

*using **findFn**, you can pretty quickly find the function you want **even though** you have no idea which Package it's in*

Answer (score 22):

It looks like a few options are already available, but I just stumbled across an idiomatic solution I like so I thought I'd add it to the list.

```
install.packages('proxy') # Let's be honest, you've never heard of this before.
library('proxy') # Library of similarity/dissimilarity measures for 'dist()'
dist(m, method="cosine")
```

Comment: Yes I do not know proxy package before, but I do not think this is a necessary package...

Answer (score 16):

Taking the comment from Jonathan Chang I wrote this function to mimic dist. No extra packages to load.

```
cosineDist <- function(x){
  as.dist(1 - x%*%t(x)/(sqrt(rowSums(x^2) %*% t(rowSums(x^2))))) 
}
```

Comment: why did you do 1- x*t(x)/(...) ? is that value of dissimilarity rather than similarity?

Comment: @alily the cosine formula gives a similarity. It is 1 if the vectors are pointing in the same direction. Distance measures need the value to be 0 when vectors are the same so 1 - similarity = distance. Many uses need distance rather than similarity (`hclust` for instance). Adding the `as.dist` formats the matrix as a nice R distance (basically a triangular matrix). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 9):

Check these functions [lsa::cosine()](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/lsa/html/cosine.html), [clv::dot_product()](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/clv/html/dot_product.html) and [arules::dissimilarity()](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/arules/html/dissimilarity.html)

Answer (score 5):

You can also check the vegan package: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vegan//index.html

The function vegdist in this package has a variety of dissimilarity (distance) functions, such as `manhattan`, `euclidean`, `canberra`, `bray`, `kulczynski`, `jaccard`, `gower`, `altGower`, `morisita`, `horn`,`mountford`, `raup` , `binomial`, `chao` or `cao`. Please check the .pdf in the package for a definition or consult references https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/33001/12733.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dot product matrix, you can use this function to compute the cosine similarity matrix:

```
get_cos = function(S){
  doc_norm = apply(as.matrix(dt),1,function(x) norm(as.matrix(x),"f")) 
  divide_one_norm = S/doc_norm 
  cosine = t(divide_one_norm)/doc_norm
  return (cosine)
}
```

Input S is the matrix of dot product. Simply, `S = dt %*% t(dt)`, where `dt` is your dataset.

This function is basically to divide the dot product by the norms of vectors.

Answer (score -1):

The cosine similarity is not invariant to shift. The correlation similarity maybe a better choice because fixes this problem and it is also connected to squared Euclidean distances (if data are standardized)

If you have two objects described by p-dimensional vectors of features,
`x1` and `x2` both of dimension `p`, you can compute the correlation similarity by `cor(x1, x2)`.

Note that in statistics correlation is used as a scaled moment notion, so it is naturally thought as correlation between random variables. The `cor(dataset)` function will compute correlations between columns of the data matrix.

In a typical situation with a (n x p) data matrix `X`, with units (or objects) on its rows, and variables (or features) on its columns you can compute the **correlation similarity matrix** simply by computing `cor` on the transpose of `X`, and giving the result object a `dist` class

```
as.distance(cor(t(X)))
```

By the way you can compute **correlation dissimilarity matrix** the same way. The following make a distinction about the size of the angle and the  orientation between objects' vectors

```
1 - cor(t(X))
```

This one doesn't care about the orientation, only size of the angle

```
1 - abs(cor(t(X)))
```