# Cosine similarity calculation without nested loops

Tags: r

I tried to write a similarity matrix by using cosine similarity, and I used nested loop. I know that nested loops are not always idiomatic in R, and this implementation takes a lot of time to execute.

I am wondering how can I convert this code to a code without nested loop.

```
 cosine.sim <- function(data) 
{
        data <- t(data)
        cos.sim <- matrix (data = 1, nrow = ncol(data), ncol = ncol(data))
        for(i in 1:(ncol(data)-1))
        {
                for(j in (i+1):ncol(data))
                {
                        A <- sqrt ( sum (data[,i] ^2) )
                        B <- sqrt ( sum (data[,j] ^2) )
                        C <- sum ( data[,i] * data[,j] ) 
                        cos.sim [i,j] <- C / (A * B)
                        cos.sim [j,i] <- C / (A * B)
                }
        }
        return (cos.sim)
}
```

Comment: Loops in R are fine, as long as you pre-allocate all the necessary objects. Your example is not reproducible. Paste some data and show us what the output would look like. It would also help if you describe in words or pseudo-algorithm what and how you're trying to achieve your goal.

Comment: Also, it is a good idea to avoid using functions as variable names, like `data`.

Comment: if you want to calculate the correlation coefficient, then you don't need to write such program, simply use the existed ones, for example library(Hmisc)
rcorr(x, type="pearson") or check for other types

Comment: @RomanLuštrik my data contains term document matrix for 1500 documents. My function works properly but it takes a lot of time to execute. It returns document/ document similarity of these documents.

Comment: I would move the A computation out of nested loop (as it gives the same result for each j), and maybe test if i and j are the same to avoid setting the diagonal twice (but unsure this would be quicker).

Comment: did you try a package that already do the cosine distance in a full matrix? here is a post were you can find  a discussion about it <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535234/find-cosine-similarity-in-r>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the low-level cross product function should be orders of magnitude faster than doing the same within R.

Example data

```
> set.seed(1)
> (data<-matrix(runif(30),5,6))
          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]       [,6]
[1,] 0.2655087 0.89838968 0.2059746 0.4976992 0.9347052 0.38611409
[2,] 0.3721239 0.94467527 0.1765568 0.7176185 0.2121425 0.01339033
[3,] 0.5728534 0.66079779 0.6870228 0.9919061 0.6516738 0.38238796
[4,] 0.9082078 0.62911404 0.3841037 0.3800352 0.1255551 0.86969085
[5,] 0.2016819 0.06178627 0.7698414 0.7774452 0.2672207 0.34034900
```

The following is equivalent

```
 > tcrossprod(data/sqrt(rowSums(data^2)))
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.8193235 0.8644710 0.6829105 0.5854560
[2,] 0.8193235 1.0000000 0.8523731 0.6810237 0.5835957
[3,] 0.8644710 0.8523731 1.0000000 0.7884536 0.8815997
[4,] 0.6829105 0.6810237 0.7884536 1.0000000 0.6324778
[5,] 0.5854560 0.5835957 0.8815997 0.6324778 1.0000000
```

but likely much faster than your function

```
> cosine.sim(data)
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.8193235 0.8644710 0.6829105 0.5854560
[2,] 0.8193235 1.0000000 0.8523731 0.6810237 0.5835957
[3,] 0.8644710 0.8523731 1.0000000 0.7884536 0.8815997
[4,] 0.6829105 0.6810237 0.7884536 1.0000000 0.6324778
[5,] 0.5854560 0.5835957 0.8815997 0.6324778 1.0000000
```

Comment: These are nice options.

Comment: @A.webb  can you explain me why you did tcrosspod(data/sqrt(rowSums(data^2))) instead of tcrossprod(data)/sqrt(rowsums(data^2))?

Comment: @alily To match the OP. I don't think the other option is equivalent.